# UE4 "Failed To Launch Editor" | UE4 build from source error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I have a problem launching my UE4 project, whenever I try to launch it I get an error "*Filed To Launch Edito*r".
[image]

I'm using a **github UE4.24 version**, followed all steps to build the engine which was successful the first time, after a month of working on a new c++ game project in UE4 & built the solution & tried to launch the project I get this error now. I tried deleting binaries folder of the engine & rebuilding the engine again however I get this error now:
[image]

Output Message when building engine:
..........
..........
1>  [2363/2364] UE4Editor-UnrealEd.dll
1>     CrÚation de la bibliothÞque C:\UE4.24.0-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UnrealEd\UE4Editor-UnrealEd.suppressed.lib et de l'objet C:\UE4.24.0-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UnrealEd\UE4Editor-UnrealEd.suppressed.exp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3075: The command "....\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UE4Editor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
1>Done building project "UE4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

output log when building game project:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the output window - you probably have a ubt error.

Comment: @George I have updated the question to contain the output log

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reinstall unreal engine 4 because it may have a component or tool that is missing. one of the tools that I can see here is UnrealbuildTool.exe[image]